# plot with logarithmic y scale and negative values

Tags: r, logging, plot, yaxis

I have a set of data with both negative and positive values. I would like to present them on a plot with y axis in logarithmic scale. As some of the values are negative, log="y" doesn't work. How to overcome this?

Comment: This is not so much a programming question as a math question. You will probably get more of a response on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Alternatively, provide a subset of your data, show us the code you are using that doesn't work and the error it is providing, and with a reproducible example there is better chance that someone will be able to help you. Thanks :)

Comment: You can try an `asinh` transform of your data. Not sure if I recommend it though... Also see https://www.r-bloggers.com/modeling-trick-the-signed-pseudo-logarithm/amp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments. I've solved the problem by myself: instead of using simple plot() for generating the graph, I've used ggplot2 package with scale_y_log() function to present linear units at logarithmic scale (including negative values).

However, I have one more - similar - question, which can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048987/two-y-axes-for-the-same-data-but-different-scale/)